# Why to use Interceptor or Filters when we have Validator

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, interceptor

I am learning spring framework and I am confused about the situation when to use Interceptor and when to use Validator. Hibernate and JSR provides plenty of validation annotation so what's the use of interceptor. Suppose we want to check whether the field is empty or not then what is the recommended way JSR annotation or Interceptor.

I just want to know when should I choose Interceptors over Validators.

Comment: By interceptor, do you mean something like spring's `HandlerInterceptorAdapter` or are you talking about Hibernate interceptors?

Comment: Spring Interceptors

Answer (score 0):

Interceptor and Validation are separate concepts, that may or may not work together. They are not exclusive or conflicted in any way.

Filter and Interceptors are constructs that are well suited for cross-cutting concerns, and reusable code that is not directly related to business logic. Validation is one such concerns, but so is logging, auditing, security.

Filters and Interceptors are also centered around the lifecycle of Servlets or Spring Controller handler methods, they concern is the logic that is executing before or after.

Validation doesn't have this facet, typically, you'll validate before the handler, but given a certain context you can decide otherwise.

---

With respect to Naros comment. As he mentioned. The main intent behind the Validation specification is to promote reuse of the validation logic as this is the kind of concern that typically involves and executes in different tiers.

So as said, separate concepts, targeting different problems.

Comment: I'd argue its important not only to validate before the handler, but the service/business tier or persistence tier should be doing that too.  This is especially important when you share your persistence or service tier code across multiple projects where other projects aren't web-based.